# How to take layer from .psd in Mac OS?

Tags: photoshop, layer

I have a .psd file with a lot of layers, I need to take one of them as a new image (with size of layer)
I know that in Windows its: copy layer, Ctrl+N and its set size of layer here, but in Mac OS it doesn`t.
How to do this in Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hold the option key and click on layer's visibility (eye) icon, then crop it if you need to, and save it as a new file.